# Moving Facebook Like Button JavaScript to jQuery script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-like

I'm attempting to implement a Facebook like button on a web page on a domain which was recently upgraded to SSL. The sample code Facebook provides doesn't work for me. I keep getting this error when attempting to use Facebook's like button code:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided (http://mywebsite.com) does not match the recipient window's
>   origin (https://mywebsite.com)

I completely cleaned out all `http://` references throughout my project, so I'm a bit stumped. I did find a post which suggested the problem I'm encountering might have to do with the code running before the page is fully loaded.  With that in mind, I'd like to delay running JavaScript until the page is loaded.

So let's say they want me to put this code just inside the `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then I put my button somewhere on the page:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyPage/" data-width="100" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

How would I move the JavaScript they want me to embed inside the body of the `<body>` tag into my `script.js` file? I tried this, but I'm kinda rusty on jQuery, so I wanted to see if I'm fouling up what I'm attempting to do (spoiler: I probably am):

```
(function($) {
  $(".fb-like").loaded(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
    // also tried adding https: in front of it, like so
    // js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
})
```

**Update**

Based on comments, I created an App on the Facebook developer portal, classified it as "Business" and enabled it publicly.

I put the following JavaScript code inside the `<body>` tag, per Facebook's instructions.

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I also cleaned out the code I put in my `scripts.js` file so that all the code for the like button is on the html page.

I put the button inside a visible portion of the markup inside the `<body>` tag. I checked that the width of the button isn't set to zero. I refreshed the page, I nuked the browser cache (Safari and Chrome).

If I type **https**://mywebsite.com/my-page-with-like-button.html in the browser, I still get this error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided (http://mywebsite.com) does not match the recipient window's
>   origin (https://mywebsite.com)

...and nothing appears.

If I type in **http**://mywebsite.com/page-with-like-button.html in the browser, the page loads without an error, but the like button doesn't appear.

Any ideas re: what I'm mucking up are greatly appreciated. The last time I did this, it was a 5 minute project. Now, I'm on day 2 of fiddling with it.

Comment: Facebook has these methods as the recommended way to implement their content/APIs. It really is  the right way to do it (their examples)  and sometimes the only way. How does their example specifically not work for you?

Comment: Thank you for reading. The domain I'm working on was upgraded to an SSL certificate. I've cleaned out all the `http` references and replaced with `https`, but console keeps logging the error `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided (http://mywebsite.com) does not match the recipient window's origin (https://mywebsite.com)`

Comment: I think as long as you use `fbAsyncInit`, Facebook will make sure your code is run before theirs.

Comment: @PHPglue Thanks for reading. I don't have that in my code. What's that look like?

Comment: Yes Facebook is pretty strict on how to use their API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart You also would need to setup a Facebook app to obtain an id you can lock down to the domain.

Comment: @lscmaro They'r pretty strict how you post in their developer forum. LOL. I tried to post a link to an URL and it wouldn't let me do it. That's why I came here with the Q.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: Thank you to those who responded. Elsewhere on Facebook's developer site, it said I don't need an App to use the like button code. That post seems to contradict what I read elsewhere. I'll go the JS SDK route and see how far I get.

Answer (score 0):

To somewhat answer your question on how to add the FB script to an external js file. *This is a best guess scenario;* You could try and add it as it is in the example:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I believe this would still need to be included before your `<div>` holding the like button. If you have other js inside that file, this should be at the top and outside of any other JS you have. for example:

```
(function(d,s,id){ /* FB script */}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
(function($){ /* your other JS */ })(jQuery);
```

This is purely a guess, and not the recommended 'FB official' way. So as long as you can add what you need in a js file just after the `<body>` element, that should work. I also assume you would need the correct markup for this in the HTML file(s) for this also, meaning:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="yourJsFileWithFB.js"></script>
.... 
..... 
<div class="fb-like"></div>
... 
.....
</body>
```

Plus all the data attributes referenced on the like button mentioned in the example [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)